# Microsoft VBScript compilation e rror: Expected end of statement

Tags: vbscript

I'm getting an error when I run this script:

```
WshShell.Run "%comspec% /k "& Chr(34)C:\Programs\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe"&Chr(34) &" -startvm "&szVMName ,0
```

This is the error:
(1, 38) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement

I'm running this in Win7 Pro sp1
I would like the script to start a VirtualBox guest minimized.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to resolve the error?

Thank you,

Docfxit

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your quotes right.  Try:

```
WshShell.Run "%comspec% /k " & Chr(34) & "C:\Programs\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe" & Chr(34) & " -startvm " & szVMName & " ,0"
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I'm now getting another error: (1, 9) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Syntax error